# Statistical significance of increase in correlation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test, calibration, fisher-transform

I have a sample with some individuals, and also three variables measured for each individual, let's say $A$, $B$ and $C$.

There is a mild correlation between $A$ and $B$ and a mild correlation between $A$ and $C$

- $r_{AB} = 0.44$, and
- $r_{AC} = 0.47$.

I want to test if this increase in correlation is significant. I have come across two ways:

1. Fisher's z-Test for comparing 2 correlation coefficients
2. Wolfe's t-Test for comparing dependent correlation coefficients

I calculated the *p-values* of each test to be, respectively, $0.53$ and $2.8\times 10^{-5}$. From my understanding, Wolfe's t-Test is most appropriate in this situation, but the huge difference in p-value is making me wonder if I did something wrong along the way...

How exactly does one test whether one correlation coefficient value is significantly higher then another?

Comment: This could get rather involved because the two correlation coefficients are not independent (so the Fisher p-value you obtained is meaningless). But before you plunge into that, could you please tell us how you plan to *interpret* a difference in correlation coefficients? What practical meaning would it have for you?  (Incidentally, unless you have a *large* amount of data--around 15000 or more individuals--the difference between 0.44 and 0.47 will not be significant when they are independent.) Aren't you also interested in the correlation between $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Interpretation: The three variables are all estimates of the same thing (let's call it _the thing_). $A$ is known to be the best measure, but for various reasons (e.g. time to calculate), $B$ and $C$ are preferable. I'm assuming that a better correlation with $A$ means a better correlation with _the thing_. I am not really interested in the correlation between $B$ and $C$, but given their high dependence, it will be high.

Comment: You might also be interested in threads on this site related to [tag:calibration] and [inverse regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22inverse+regression%22). Two things to check before proceeding are (1) linearity of the relationships and (2) homoscedasticity.  Identifying and correcting these can improve your ability to use $B$ and $C$ as surrogates for $A$. An additional possibility that might be available to you is to use *both* of $B$ and $C$ to predict $A$.